# How to install windows server 2008 r2 Hyper-V on Windows 7, through virtual machine?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines

I have one computer that running windows 7 and want to have a Dev Environment running on this machine.

I tried to install Windows Server 2008 r2 with Hyper-V role on a VirtualBox virtual machine, but I can't get this role to be installed, since it's need a raw access to the processor.

My goal is to have a virtualized windows server that running Hyper-V, that I can install on it all the machines that I want to have in my environment: 2 IIS servers, 1 SQL Server, Load Balancer, and build server.

Can I get a little help from you guys, to help me achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: by getting rid of the illusion that you can do that.

A Hyper-Visor needs raw hardware access. So, it can not run virtualized. Get usedto it.

What you CAN do is install WIndows Server in a VHD file and then boot from that instead your Windows 7.

> My goal is to have a virtualized
>   windows server that running Hyper-V,

When deluisions meet reality, reality wins. Reality says: Hyper-V does not run within a virtual machine.

Alterantives:

- Boot into Server 2008 R2 installed in Hyper-V
- Dump Windows 7. Install Server 2008 R2 and use that as primary operating system. You CAN make it behave and look like a Windows 7 install.

I personally do - depending what I do:

- Develop in a virtual machine on a number of larger virtualizing servers
- Use my own workstation to boot into a vhd mounted server 2008 to use virtualiaztion there (mostly for training - allows me to show off a domain without bringing more than a little cube with 16gb RAM).

Comment: It turns out that I can't have a VHD file for Window Server 2008 R2,  Virtual PC can't run 64bit OS. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprovirt/thread/37e350b3-c1c4-4c5f-83da-caf8589cdfb4

Comment: That's not what he meant.  Forget about Virtual PC: it is not useful to you for this project.  He meant that you could boot Server 2008 R2 *natively* from a VHD file.

Comment: Exactly. Ever sind Windows 7 / 2008 R2 you can MOUNT AND BOOT from a VHD file.

Comment: Do you get support for Dual Screen on your computer? Do you get 1092*1080 resolution on it? As I found out, Windows server 2008 R2 that run Hyper-V, aren't capable of installing a driver the video card.

Comment: Hm... it works for me ;) Never used a dual screen with Hyper-V though. I use it mostly for training (customers dont have two screens). Otherwise I RDP into the VM (on a server) and get multiple screens there (thanks to Windows 7 support for multiple screens).

Answer (score 2):

Hyper-V can't be ran from within any other hypervisor, VMWare's ESXi can however.

Comment: So, maybe should I create the all servers that I want, using a VirtualBox virtual machine? is this option have any drawback over using Hyper-V?

Comment: Well Hyper-V is a far more 'production-ready' hypervisor, whereas VB is more of a 'desktop' product but their basic functionality is pretty comparible. What you're trying to do is more of a personal development machine, you can always install Hyper-V as a bare hypervisor on your W7 box (W7 will effectively run as a VM at that point) - it may not be what you're after but is another option. Hope you have lots of memory :)

Comment: I have 8 RAM. I didn't get your solution. DOes it mean that I can install hyper-v on my windows 7, and don't reinstall my windows 7 as VM? Do you think that for my situation, that I want a few (like 5) servers to have, is maybe good to install each one as a separate VM? or it better recommend to haev them all on a one Hyper-V windows server?

Comment: How can I achieve what you'he suggested? should I use a VirtualPC for that? (I says that it's not compatible with my windows). it seems like a nice solution :)

Comment: Not virtualPC no, just Hyper-V Server 2008 R2, the stand alone hypervisor - have a look here; http://www.microsoft.com/hyper-v-server/en/us/default.aspx

Comment: Can I return to my 'normal' W7 after installing this? or it will be always virtualized from now on? Does 8GB seems enough for you for 4 Windows server virtual machines?

Comment: I don't know for a fact but I don't think you can, that said W7's bare-metal restoration system is very good. As for the 8GB, it depends on how much memory you assign to each VM - Hyper-V doesn't do shared/compressed memory.

Answer (score 0):

Today I try something and it works! first, you can install Hyper-V server 2008 r2 in VirtualBox, you can enable all the things and administer it from a server 2008 or by a client like this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887

The other way is to install windows server 2008 r2 and you can add a role by comand console like this:

```
Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

And no errors!

If you want to, can add the MMC whit this command:

```
Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-Clients
```

Comment: You've been able to do this for several years with VMWare Workstation. I've setup two Hyper-V servers with a FreeNAS shared storage and demo'ed live migration and failover all within VMWare Workstation on a windows 7 laptop.